# driver.manage().window().maximize() is not working for chrome in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Selenium, I am facing some issue when open browser in chrome then full screen is not working.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

**Replace to**

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

And it's working

Comment: How to achieve this in Cypress?

Answer (score 1):

As per [manage().window().maximize() method not maximize a correct window](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=596) using `driver.manage().window().maximize();` to maximize the `Chrome Browser` is not the optimum way. Instead use **ChromeOptions** to maximize the *Chrome Browser* as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

To open *Chrome Browser* in `kiosk` mode you can also use:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk");
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

As an alternative you can also use the argument **`window-size`** as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thank you! Kiosk mode solved my team's automation issue. This should be the preferred answer.